# Loading Data of the UITableView while not being displayed on the screen

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a scenario where i need to select number of products. Each product has a set of data related to it which needs to be selected from its displayed TableView. And if the submit button is pressed it should check all tableView  data that has been checked or not, to show appropriate message

On the first instance i am able to show the data of the first product on the first tableView . Then i am saving other tableViews of the individual products in an array. But the other tableView doesn't contain the related data.

Here is the code to save TableView in an array after displaying first TableView;

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(loadTableViewsInArray) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

-(void)loadTableViewsInArray{
for (int i = 0; i < sourceData.count-1; i++) {
    [tableViewArray addObject:[self allocTableView]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [dataTableView reloadData]; });
}
```

here **sourceData** is total number of products

Comment: What is the issue? what you want exactly ?

Comment: Can you show your UITableViewDataSource methods?

Comment: i want to save all the tableViews in an array along with its data loaded in the cells